# openssl-encrypt, PHP vs commandline - how to make IVs same

Tags: php, command-line, openssl

I am trying to encrypt the data using PHP and openssl command line, expected same encrypted data, but I am getting different data.

On linux, this is my openssl -version

```
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

I tried to pass 48 bytes of data, hoping that might avoid padding. But no luck.
I observed IVs are different so tried to use IV = 905E17D5F5E4939D0000000000000000 in PHP code also. But I got warning openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 32 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher, truncating in

tried with/without -nosalt options on command line.

```
<?php
// encrypt/decrypt string 
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = '905e17d5f5e4939d48bd04ff47f9de906375b87b67068b2ce5d1bbbbc8dca291';
    $iv = '905e17d5f5e4939d';
    $string = "123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG";

    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);  


echo $output;
?> 

nEUDtXM7OQt32YEx778BgqZfocXrNNA9AihkioWZo9ri9p11DtxUpTFO30AHUk41F9PUBLu6YlYu/mdLcOZ3Cg==
```

where as openssl from linux command line:

```
echo "123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG" |openssl enc -base64 -e -aes-256-cbc  -K 905e17d5f5e4939d48bd04ff47f9de906375b87b67068b2ce5d1bbbbc8dca291 -iv 905e17d5f5e4939d -nosalt -p

key=905E17D5F5E4939D48BD04FF47F9DE906375B87B67068B2CE5D1BBBBC8DCA291
iv =905E17D5F5E4939D0000000000000000
c4JHI/8SIQkx7GXM2SclOXhbmR9vYBFLHt/jY0x7pJou9J2INJBQMISRYH4CPjvy
QDeyOWpcEEN/N6FnSdF0EA==
```

what am I missing here? how can I make sure both PHP and openssl -command line will use same IV/Key? How can make sure the padding is same in both if there is any? I want see same results on both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
  <?php
// encrypt/decrypt string 
$output = false;
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$key = hex2bin('905E17D5F5E4939D48BD04FF47F9DE906375B87B67068B2CE5D1BBBBC8DCA291');
$iv = hex2bin('905E17D5F5E4939D0000000000000000');
$string = "123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG";

$output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);  


echo $output;
?>
```

and in the CLI

```
echo -n "123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG123456789ABCDEFG" |openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 905e17d5f5e4939d48bd04ff47f9de906375b87b67068b2ce5d1bbbbc8dca291 -iv 905E17D5F5E4939D0000000000000000 -nosalt
```

The differences are

1. I removed the line break in the CLI with `echo -n "foo"` instead of `echo "foo"`
   (Otherwise you encrypt a different string ten in the PHP code).
2. The CLI uses a hexadecimal string,Therefore also in PHP the key string needs to be converted to hex with `hex2bin()`.